# Using ImageMagick convert a PSD to various Android density images

Tags: automation, imagemagick, android-image, psd, image-conversion

I have a PSD that contains the graphics I require split onto various layers and I am wanting to use ImageMagick to convert these into the various png files. I have managed to work this out using.

```
convert file.psd export.png
```

I would like to be able to turn these into the various densities that android supports

- 320 dpi (xhdpi)
- 240 dpi (hdpi)
- 160 dpi (mdpi)
- 120 dpi (ldpi)

This is where I get confused since I don't understand how to perform the above conversions.

Answer (score 1):

```
convert -size <width>x<height> pattern:CrossHatch30 -scale <dpi>% <picture file name>
```